# Magento 2 - Error importing a CSV file : The " " category name can not be used to generate Latin URL key

Tags: magento2, import-products, url-key

I'm trying to upload a csv file and I get the error:

```
Invalid URL key. The " " category name can not be used to generate Latin URL key. Please add URL key or change category name using Latin letters and numbers to avoid generating URL key issues.
```

However the `url_key` column has value for all products.

Any ideas?

Comment: maybe you have an empty line somewhere that contains some spaces in once cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento has some ways to automaticaly generate an url key (generaly based on the category/product name).

This error is thrown when Magento detects that the url_key could not be generated, even if the category has a name.

Here is the specific condition throwing the error :

```php
if (empty($urlKey) && !empty($category->getName())) {
```

In your case, it might come from 2 sources :

- You have a cell with a single space as the "category name"
- As suggested in a comment, you have an empty or incomplete line in your file

Comment: In some categories there was an extra "/" and raised this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This error is telling Category url key is wrong, you should check the category url

- check url_rewrite table to see any empty url
- check category attribute table to check url key is correct
- switch store_view of the category to see any empty url is ticked and replacing the default value.